# how to add footer template to react kendo grid

Tags: css, reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

I want to add an aggregate of records at the end of the Kendo Grid (`table`), bellow all of the `tr`(s) [like this sample](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/aggregates).

Sadly, Kendo React UI grid only supports [footer for groups](https://stackblitz.com/run/?file=app%2Fmain.js) and footer templates are not supported in Kendo React for the data grid.

I have to modify the CSS of the last row of the table manually :

```
.general-ledger-balance .k-grid-content table > tbody > tr.k-master-row:last-child {
    font-weight: bold;
    position: fixed;
}
```

But this solution is messing `aggregate tr` up.

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no build-in way of adding global aggregates, however there is already feature request logged in Github. You can follow the feature progress there:

- https://github.com/telerik/kendo-react/issues/47